# Bootcamp and code sandbox challenge is telling me axios is not defined

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I don't know where my code is going wrong. The challenge is to display the current temperature of my location in the h1 of the page but my console is telling me axios is not defined. I am not sure if it is because I am using codesandbox or if there is an error I am missing in my code. Thanks

JS

```
function showTemperature(response) {
  console.log();
  let temperature = Math.round(response.data.main.temp);

  let heading = document.querySelector("h1");
  heading.innerHTML = `The outside temperature is ${temperature}℃`;
}

function retrievePosition(position) {
  let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  let units = "metric";
  let apiKey = "cb64da9857db4762d73f7ab9b0ccec88";
  let apiEndpoint = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
  let apiUrl = `${apiEndpoint}?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${units}`;
  console.log(apiUrl);

  axios.get(apiUrl).then(showTemperature);
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(retrievePosition);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>She Codes Plus</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="She Codes Plus Logo" class="logo" />
    <h1>JavaScript Geolocation API</h1>

    <h3>JS Challenge 1</h3>
    <p>Log your current latitude and longitude using the Geolocation API</p>

    <h3>JS Challenge 2</h3>
    <p>Log the current temperature where you are.</p>

    <h3>JS Challenge 3</h3>
    <p>
      Change the h1 of this page by the current temperature
    </p>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error you described here in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xkem2pf/) - is it possible you've changed anything between what you're working with on your local machine and what you've posted here?

Comment: I just reviewed it and no it is all the same, but the bootcamp uses codesandbox to submit assignments so I need it to work on codesandbox. But when I opened your jsFiddle it doesn't appear to me displaying the current temperature either.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed Axios? I don't think you are importing Axios to your file.

```
npm install axios
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: The OP is clearly trying to use `axios` in-browser and has included it as a `<script>` reference in their HTML.